# strings flipping

Tags: javascript, python, string

the original input ?
huhhhgghghjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjjhjhjhhjhjhjhjhjjhhjjhhhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjjh  hjgjghhjgvjghvjgh hah bhjbh  hb hb h
 ***UPDATED QUESTION***

```
const scrambled = list => {
  let storage = [];
  let scrambledWords = list[1];
  let letterCount = 0;
  let dict = list[0].split(',').reduce((obj,ele) =>{
    obj[ele] = true;
    return obj;
  },{});

  for(let i = 0; i< word;i++){
    if(i === Object.keys(dict[1])){

    }
  }

  return storage.join()
};
```

Comment: Can you include the code which rearranges letters at Question?

Comment: Can you provide some additional input/output examples? If you have the first line, what are you really trying to do with the rest? Are there instances where the words wouldn't be present and you'd need to detect them?

Comment: Without knowing the _mangling_ code you can only take guesses as how the original input string was structured - for example, how will you know in what order are your words?

Comment: @mkaatman I added another input/output example. I get your thinking and i thought the same regarding the rest of the lines. Thats just how the code is inputed from a file

Comment: @zwer I actually don't know how the code is being imported. The question was to rearrange the input from the given example. No code was given on the input format.

Comment: In that case this is an unsolvable problem. You cannot discern the order from the given input.

Comment: On example 2, how would you know it was Chicago bulls and not bulls chicago? On example 1 it doesn't have a "D" so how would you get hello world?

Comment: @mkaatman That was my fault I forgot to include the D.  I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to store the indexes of the characters at original string as properties to an object, where value is set to character. Iterate object properties to create, set or replace rearranged string to original input characters indexes.

```js
let str = "Hello World";

function scramble(s) {
  const indexes = [];
  const len = Array.from({
    length: s.length
  }, (_, index) => index);
  let scrambledString = "";
  do {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len.length);
    let curr = len.splice(index, 1)[0];
    indexes.push(curr);
    scrambledString += s[curr];
  } while (len.length);
  return {scrambledString, indexes};
}

function unscramble(s, arr) {
  let res = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res += s[arr[arr.indexOf(i)]];
  }
  return res
}

let scrambled = scramble(str);

console.log(scrambled.scrambledString);

let unscrambled = unscramble(str, scrambled.indexes);

console.log(unscrambled);
```

Comment: This is as far as air got with your approach. I was able to create an object with a given input

Comment: function scrambled(str){
var pass = str.replace(',',':');
var arr = pass.split(':');
var final_obj = {};
arr.forEach(function(el,i){
  var b = i + 1, c = b/2, e = c.toString();
     if(e.indexOf('.') != -1 ) {
     final_obj[el] = arr[i+1];
  } 
}); 

 return final_obj
}

scrambled("Hello World")

Comment: What is expected result of `scrambled` call?